# Can't select older iOS SDK Simulator Version in Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium

I have installed the SDK's for 6.x and 7.0 in xcode and I'd like to test my app on ios6 in the simulator using titanium studio.

After poking around for some time I still can't find a way to select a different iOS version in my run configurations. As you can see, SDK's are installed and I can select them in the simulator itself, but the only way to test the app is by launching 7.0 (Titanium won't launch anything else).

Manually switching between versions and relaunching the app from titanium doesn't help either.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Titanium Studio has problem with simulator settings. Compiling project from console with `titanium build -p ios` will run your app on simulator with current settings. Also you can use additional flags to force different type of simulator:

```
 --retina           use the retina version of the iOS Simulator
 --sim-64bit        in combination with --retina flag & --tall flag, start the 64-bit tall version of the retina simulator
 --tall             in combination with --retina flag, start the tall version of the retina device
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It's not a solution, but in my case a restart and some time later fixed the problem above. I can now select 6.x in the "Simulator Version" combo. I hate it when I can't provide a clear solution :).

Comment: Problem depends a lot from os environment and configuration. Usually just couple good tip and/or guidelines to figure out what's wrong and how to solve it is good enough :)